# Href having echo does not work in php 7

Tags: php

I am having this piece of php code. Which was working on php 5. Recently I updated to php 7 and its not working. Is there anything missing after upgrading to php 7. Here is my php code:

```
 <?
define ("ROOT_DIR", "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/"); ?>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="<?echo ROOT_DIR?>main.css"/>
```

Its unable to load main.css and also there are few links like:

```
<li> <a href="<?echo ROOT_DIR?>mapshop/index.php" >Mapshop test tools</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="<?echo ROOT_DIR?>mapshop/certificate.php" >Durham certificate test</a> </li>
```

When I take mouse over these links, it shows http://myserver.com/`<?echo ROOT_DIR?>`mapshop/index.php. Its not parsing/executing the echo command which I am expecting.

Comment: Does it work if you add semi-colons after the echo ROOT_DIR?

Comment: What is `<?echo`, does that even exist? I've never seen that before. Does it work with `<?= ROOT_DIR ?>` or `<?php echo ROOT_DIR; ?>` for example?

Comment: @Paul — That's a `<?` and an `echo` without the (optional) space between them.

Comment: Yea thanks, after seeing the duplicate question you added, I started realizing what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<?echo ROOT_DIR?>
```

to

```
<?php echo ROOT_DIR ?>
<!-- |             |    
     |             |    
     +-------------+------------ make sure to add those spaces!
```

Comment: @Downvoter, commenting your downvote would be much appreciated.